# comparing probability of two polyhedron dice

Tags: dice

I'm trying to figure out the probabilities associated with rolling two different types of dice and one coming out higher than the other.

Example:

Rolling a 4 sided die vs a 6 sided die, what's the probability that the 6 sider will roll higher?

Rolling a 6 sided die vs an 8 sided die, what's the probability that the 8 sider will roll higher?

Rolling an 8 sided die vs a 10 sided die, what's the probablity that the 10 sider will roll higher?

I haven't done any statistics in way too many years and am really rusty.

Comment: As per the first example: there are $4\times 6=24$ possibilities. If on a 4-sider (assuming it goes from 1 to 4) you get 1, then $2-6$ on a 6-sider (assuming it goes from 1 to 6) are higher (i.e., 5 out of 6 possibilities). Analogously, 2 on 4-sider yields $3-6$ (4/6 possibilities), next 3/6 and 2/6. Summing up, $5+4+3+2=14$, so the probability is $14/24=7/12\approx 58\%$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can look at the brute force way of calculating this, then we derive a simpler formula

The amount of combinations for outcomes in a 4-side vs 6-side is `4 * 6 = 24`

```
D4 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4
D6 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

The occurrences where `D4 >= D6` is:

```
D4 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
D6 1 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4
```

$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10$ **Note this pattern**

Therefore the occurrences for `D4 < D6` is $24 - 10 = 14$

So the chances of you rolling a `D4 < D6` is $14/24 = 7/12$

---

We can interpret from the example that you can effectively calculate this by a general formula:

### Rolling a X sided die vs a Y sided die, what's the probability that the Y sider will roll higher?

We want to find the chance of `DX < DY`

The amount of combinations for outcomes in a X-side vs Y-side is $X * Y = XY$

Occurrences of `DX >= DY` is $1 + 2 + 3 + ... + X$

Therefore `DX < DY` is $XY - (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + X)$

Finally, the chance of `DX < DY` is $[XY - (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + X)] / XY$

Or, $1 - [(1 + 2 + 3 + ... + X) / XY]$

---

## Therefore

`D4 < D6`
$$1 - [(1 + 2 + 3 + 4) / (4 * 6)] = 1 - [10/24] = 14/24 = 7/12$$
`D6 < D8`
$$1 - [(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6) / (6 * 8)] = 1 - [21/48] = 27/48 = 9/16$$
`D8 < D10`
$$1 - [(1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8) / (8 * 10)] = 1 - [36/80] = 44/80 = 11/20$$

Sorry about the formatting, I'm still new to using this

Edit: Wrong Substitution for the last examples, sorry

Comment: awesome. I figured out the brute force method, but I couldn't quite nail the calculations.

Comment: One can also easily derive a general formula for $X,Y=X+2$ as $P=\frac{3+X}{4+2X}$, from which $\lim\limits_{X\rightarrow\infty}P=\frac{1}{2}$, and for arbitrary $X,Y$: $P=\frac{2Y-X-1}{2Y}$.

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot about changing $XY$ in the last few substitutions @TH1981, please note about the errata

Comment: @Evening - np. I understood the principal of the formula and actually missed the error in the details :)

Answer (score 4):

#### Analysis

Let's answer all the questions at once by supposing you are independently throwing an $m$-sided die (call it $X$) and an $n$-sided die (call it $Y$), where each die has faces numbered 1, 2, 3, *etc.* and all faces have equal probabilities of occurring.

The independence assumption means that any particular outcome where the first die shows the value $i$ (between $1$ and $m$) and the second die shows the value $j$ (between $1$ and $n$) is $1/(nm).$

The *Law of Total Probability* says you can break down the event "$Y$ is greater than $X$" into separate events corresponding to the value shown by $X$ and sum the probabilities of each separate event.  Here goes:

1. **$X$ shows a 1.**  For $Y$ to exceed $X,$ it must therefore show a 2, 3, *etc*, up to $n.$  There are $n-1$ ways in which this can happen, each of which with probability $1/(nm),$ so the chance is $(n-1)/(nm).$
2. **$X$ shows a 2.**  For $Y$ to exceed $X,$ it must therefore show a 3, 4, *etc*, up to $n.$  There are $n-2$ ways in which this can happen, each of which with probability $1/(nm),$ so the chance is $(n-2)/(nm).$
3. **The pattern potentially continues** up to the case where $X$ shows the value $n,$ in which case there's no way $Y$ can exceed $X.$
4. Obviously we need to stop with the case $X=m,$ because it cannot result in any larger number.  The probability that $Y$ exceeds $X$ in this case is $(n-m)/(nm).$

---

#### Solution

Summing all these possibilities *and assuming $n \ge m$* (as in the question) gives

> When $n \ge m,$ $$\eqalign{\Pr(Y \gt X) &= \frac{n-1}{nm} + \frac{n-2}{nm} + \cdots + \frac{n-m}{nm} \\&= \frac{n(n-1) - (n-m)(n-m-1)}{2} \times \frac{1}{nm}.}$$

The left hand factor counts the number of outcomes where $Y$ exceeds $X$ while the right hand factor of $1/(nm)$ converts that to a probability.  (The count can be simplified to $m(2n-m-1)$ for computational purposes, but that simpler formula obscures the idea that led to the answer.)

In case $m$ is the larger number, the sum stops with $n-m=0$ giving a  simpler value:

> When $n \lt m,$ $$\Pr(Y \gt X) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} \times \frac{1}{nm}.$$

---

#### Illustration

For example, the $4(2(6)-4-1)/2 = 14$ possible ways in which a d6 can exceed a d4 are

```
d4 (X): 1 1 1 1 1 | 2 2 2 2 | 3 3 3 | 4 4 
d6 (Y): 2 3 4 5 6 | 3 4 5 6 | 4 5 6 | 5 6
```

and indeed the count is $5+4+3+2 = 14.$  **The chance therefore is $14/(4\times 6)= 7/12.$**  **Similarly, the answers in the other two cases are $27/48$ (d8 *vs* d6) and $44/80=11/20$ (d10 *vs* d8).**

If you're interested in the chance that a d4 will exceed a d6 (an example of where $n$ is less than $m,$ here are the possibilities:

```
d6 (X): 1 1 1 | 2 2 | 3
d4 (Y): 2 3 4 | 3 4 | 4
```

and indeed the count is $3+2+1 = 6 = 4(4-1)/2.$

---

#### Comments

Notice that $14/24$ and $6/24$ do not sum to $1,$ because there's a third possibility of a tie.  Evidently there are four ways a tie can occur in the case, giving a chance of $4/(4\times6).$  The chances to add to $1$: $14/24 + 6/24 + 4/24 = 24/24=1,$ as they ought.  This is a helpful check of the formulas and the arithmetic.

---

#### Brute force calculation

Finally, since you have a good SO reputation, you must have an aptitude for programming.  **With smallish values of $m$ and $n$ you can just generate all the possibilities and count them up.**  Here's an `R` implementation to illustrate:

```
f <- function(m, n) nrow(subset(expand.grid(Y=1:n, X=1:m), Y > X))
```

This does not do the division by $nm$ so that you can obtain the *count* of possibilities directly.  Examples:

```
> f(4,6)
[1] 14

> f(6,8)
[1] 27

> f(8,10)
[1] 44

> f(6,4)
[1] 6
```

Comment: @Corey I want to thank you for your generous attention to improving this post.

Comment: The pleasure is all mine :)